# Stack too deep, try removing local variables when using remix

Tags: solidity, compilation, local-variables

while  compiling  in remix i get the above error:

```
 CompilerError: Stack too deep, try removing local variables.
    --> work/youkie.sol:1015:80:
     |
1015 |         (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
```

here is the code part

```
   function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
    (uint256 tTransferAmount, uint256 tFee, uint256 tLiquidity, uint256 tCharity , uint256 tMarketing) = _getTValues(tAmount);
    (uint256 rAmount, uint256 rTransferAmount, uint256 rFee) = _getRValues(tAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing, _getRate());
    return (rAmount, rTransferAmount, rFee, tTransferAmount, tFee, tLiquidity, tCharity, tMarketing);
}
```

Comment: Try to follow the compiler advice, removing local variables, check the answers in the linked question for other solutions.

Comment: no result..still has the same error

Comment: Check the linked question for other workarounds: using a struct or array instead of passing so many parameters, splitting the function in two or more, only return values that will be used, etc.